# Synchronization between SQL Server Express and any light-weight database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, entity-framework, database-replication

We are developing a windows desktop application, that requires local caching (synchronization) of a remote SQL Server Express database. We are accessing this database over WCF.

So, we need to synchronize the remote database with a local, light-weight database, that is supported by Entity Framework, like SQLCE or SQLLite.

We know that Sync Framework does not support SQLCE 4.0 and we wish to avoid Sync Framework (because it looks like a dead technology) and SQLCE 3.5 (because it's old).

Is there any other way to perform the desired synchronization between SQL Server Express and any light-weight database supported by Entity Framework?

Comment: Tool / Service recommendations are off topic here. Sorry, dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use Zumero for SQL Server, supports all your requirements - uses SQLite

Comment: Thank you very much, we were not aware of this product. Seems like a good solution, but not exactly what we need. What we need is a framework exactly like Sync Framework, but with active development & support. So i think the question is: Is Sync framework the only existing developer's framework for data replication?

Comment: "Framework?" - Zumero supplies a client SDK for all platforms, and has active development and support.

Comment: Zumero is fine, it's pricing is not convenient because it is targeted in mobile applications. We would need multiple Zumero Servers, one per client. It's a good solution and if nothing else shows up i will accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but their smallest package is reasonbly priced, and it Works also on SQL Server Express